# Does $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Please, I have a challenge in solving this question. Can anyone help me?

I want to know if $\lim\limits_{x\to 1^{-}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n(n+1)}$ exists and also find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the series $\sum \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ converges, the answer is yes.

Comment: The limit of this series can be calculated so: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series

Comment: @  Logic_Problem: Thank you very much! But, how do I deal with the cases of $x$?

Comment: @Mike: do you have more information that isn’t in your question?  What cases are you referring to?

Comment: You have the left sided limit, so all $x$ are $\le 1$. Therefore the series with $x$ is majorised by the series $\sum \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$. So You have the uniform convergence.

Comment: @  abiessu: Sorry for that. I thought, $x$ was in $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint ::

Write the limit as $$\lim_{x\to 1^-} \left(\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^n}{n}\right) -\frac 1x\left(\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right) $$

Now use that $$-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^n}{n}$$ and $$-x-\ln(1-x)=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{n+1}}{n+1}$$

Comment: What has this series to do with the original one?

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 What do you mean by that?  I just used partial fractions to represent infinite summation and then used Taylor series.  And now the form obtained is much better to evaluate rather than the first one

Comment: Yes, I see. Not a direct way, but it's OK. :) The only disadvantage - You have to know about $\ln$. This cannot be generally assumed.

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42 Come on its a common Taylor expansion and not an assumption and not even that hard to prove

Comment: @  Logic_Problem_42 and Manthanein: Thank you! @ Manthanein: Please, can you help complete my proof and then, I'll mark that you've fully answered my question.

Comment: @Mike Sorry but this site promotes learning and since I have provided a hint already which simplifies the problem to a great extent,  I can't post a complete solution.  You must yourself continue with the hint.  If you get stuck up somewhere,  I can help. So try continuing yourself and ask me if you get stuck up

Comment: @ Manthanein: That's fair enough! Thanks all the time!

Comment: @You are welcome. :-))

Answer (score 1):

The given series converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ by Weierstrass M. Thus the limit of the sum is the sum of the limits. In other words, the limit in question equals

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left (\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right) = 1,$$

the last series telescoping nicely.